# Generating sequential ID using MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, sql-update, sql-insert, auto-increment

I need to generate a barcode reference for each order received. The first barcode is 200000 and increases by 1 for each subsequent order.  I have to be absolutely certain that I don't assign the same barcode to more than one order.  The project receives lots of orders and often many in very quick succession.

To overcome this issue I have created a MySQL database table called `barcodes` with an auto increment primary key. The ID of the first row is 200000.

Each time I need to generate a barcode I do an insert into the `barcodes` table and then use PHP's `mysqli_insert_id()` to get the ID inserted. I then update the `orders` table so the barcode is set to this value.

This works well and prevents me from being able to assign the same barcode to more than one order.

Is there a better way? Ideally I would have one table where I store the next available ID and then run two queries:

```
select next_barcode from barcodes where id=1
```

And then

```
update barcodes set next_barcode=next_barcode+1 where id=1
```

My concern here is that my code could call the function that performs the SELECT at exactly the same time (i.e. before the UPDATE) has run and two orders are given the same barcode.

Perhaps there is some reliable table locking approach? Or maybe my current approach is the best way to go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as concerns, `auto_increment`, which you are currently using, is the best way to go for your use case. Uniqueness is guaranteed *by design*, and the database does the heavy lifting for your under the hood.

The only possible downside is that you might experience gaps in the `id`s - for example when an `insert` fails for some reason, a sequence `id` might be lost, and the following insert will increment the `id` again, leading to a gap in the sequence.

If that's a problem for you, then one option is to use the `insert ... select` syntax to get the latest id and the new id in a single query when inserting, like:

```
insert into barcodes (id, ...)
select coalesce(max(id), 0) + 1, ...
from barcodes
```

This prevents two rows from getting the same `id`. But again, I would not recommend that; using `auto_increment` is more efficient, and simpler.

Comment: Thank you, GMB.  Good to know that the "simple" approach I am using is fine.

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing is pretty good. You will guaranteed not get the same id twice.
If you're inventing your own system for this, you will need to lock many tables, destroying concurrency or do everything via transactions. It's definitely possible to accomplish what you're doing with transactions, but the best way to go about this would probably mostly replicated what AUTO_INCREMENT already does.. it's just harder.

One thing to keep in mind that in some circumstances MySQL might skip an id in AUTO_INCREMENT, but you'll guaranteed never get the same number twice.

Comment: Thank you, Evert.  I have no problem with occasionally skipping an ID, I just need to avoid the reverse and using the same one twice.